# Use jcrontab with Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring

JCrontab seems a simple scheduling library. I would like to integrate it into my web application with Spring Framework.

However, I followed the official FAQ to start up by loadCrontabServletCL with parameter of PROPERTIES_FILE. As a result, the file cannot be found. What's wrong? How can I find it inside /WEB-INF/ ?

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>StartupJCrontab</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jcrontab.web.loadCrontabServletCL</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>PROPERTIES_FILE</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/properties/jcrontab.properties</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Answer (score -1):

Xml configuration add your spring configuration file

```
    <task:schduler id="taskScheduler"/>
    <task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="1"/>
    <task:annotation-driven executor="taskExecutor" scheduler="taskScheduler" />
```

After add configuration, in a spring bean ,you can add annotation

//schedule each  minute to run

```
@Scheduled(cron="0 * * * * *") 
public void simpleCronMethod(){ //write what you want to schedule}
```

[Spring schedule an cron](https://www.google.com.tr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html&ei=bPOSUofpPI_PsgbCuYEo&usg=AFQjCNFNVCwSjM0PIVqK-PdikXa8I0u5KQ&sig2=LCzHqjxC_6INl9uO99UbCg&bvm=bv.57127890,d.Yms) link

Comment: No, I am not using crontab. I want to use jcrontab. See http://jcrontab.sourceforge.net/